# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/hadoop/configuration/ConfigurationFactoryBean

Tags: spring, hadoop

i am using hadoop2.5.2, spring4.1, spring-data-hadoop2.0.0 RELEASE.

Whenever I specify a configuration tag using the Spring Hadoop namespace in spring bean configuration file

Spring Data Hadoop XML config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop/spring-hadoop.xsd">

<context:property-placeholder location="hadoop.properties"/>
<configuration>
    fs.defaultFS=${hd.fs}
    yarn.resourcemanager.address=${hd.rm}
    mapreduce.framework.name=yarn
    mapreduce.jobhistory.address=${hd.jh}
</configuration>
<job id="samplejob"
    input-path="${input.path}" 
    output-path="${output.path}"
    jar-by-class="com.ihub.BookXDriver"
    mapper="com.ihub.BookXMapper"
    reducer="com.ihub.BookXReducer"/>
<job-runner id="runner" run-at-startup="true"
    job-ref="samplejob" />    
</beans:beans>
```

stack trace:

```
2015-08-03 12:32:04,930 INFO  [main] support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext (AbstractApplicationContext.java:prepareRefresh(510)) - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@53533c55: startup date [Mon Aug 03 12:32:04 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-08-03 12:32:05,067 INFO  [main] xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader (XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:loadBeanDefinitions(317)) - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [com/ihub/config.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [com/ihub/config.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/hadoop/configuration/ConfigurationFactoryBean
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:414)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:452)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.ihub.BookXDriver.main(BookXDriver.java:50)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/hadoop/configuration/ConfigurationFactoryBean
    at org.springframework.data.hadoop.config.HadoopConfigParser.getBeanClass(HadoopConfigParser.java:32)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.AbstractSingleBeanDefinitionParser.parseInternal(AbstractSingleBeanDefinitionParser.java:66)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.parse(AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.java:60)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:74)
    at org.springframework.data.hadoop.config.HadoopNamespaceHandler.parse(HadoopNamespaceHandler.java:70)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1427)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1417)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:144)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:100)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.hadoop.configuration.ConfigurationFactoryBean
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 26 more
```

Answer (score 0):

This error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.hadoop.configuration.ConfigurationFactoryBean
```

is pointing out that some jar is missing from your project classpath.

ConfigurationFactoryBean class is present in spring-data-hadoop2.0.0 RELEASE. So ensure this jar is present in your project classpath.

In case required jar is present but still receiving this error, then its just that the path where jar is placed is not treated like a classpath for your project.

Comment: i have spring-data-hadoop2.0.0 RELEASE is present in my project classpath